# Show that the sequence of products $\prod_{k=1}^n (1+1/k^3)$ converges

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

$$
a_{n} = 1 + \frac{1}{n^3}
$$
Show that the sequence is converges
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{1^3}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{2^3}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{3^3}\right) \ldots \left(1 + \frac{1}{n^3}\right)
$$
I know that I should use natural logarithm but I have no clue how. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Is this the sequence {$(1+\frac{1}{n^3})^n$}?

Comment: Just for your curiosity, $a_{\infty}=\frac{\cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi }{2}\right)}{\pi }$. Nice, isn't it ?

Comment: See [convergence criteria for infinite products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria).

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*

Note that $$\ln  \left[ \left(1 + \frac{1}{1^3}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{2^3}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{3^3}\right) \ldots \left(1 + \frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right] = \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{1^3}\right) + \cdots + \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n^3}\right) $$

Now use the inequality $\ln (1 + x) \leq x$ for all $x > 0$

Comment: Why prove that
$$
ln( \left(1 + \frac{1}{1^3}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{2^3}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{3^3}\right) \ldots \left(1 + \frac{1}{n^3}\right))
$$ is converges implicate that the basic sequence is converges?

Comment: Because if we can show $\ln(a_n)$ converges, then $a_n$ converges. My hint can be used to show $\ln(a_n)$ is bounded above. It is also clearly increasing; hence it must have a limit. Therefore $a_n$ has a limit.